# What is the approximate internal volume of the USS Enterprise (TOS, pre-A)?

Tags: star-trek, uss-enterprise

I'm interested in either of two numbers. The first number would be the empty space volume that the crew walks around in, presumably including restricted access spaces like the Jeffries tubes and space inside machines that engineers and technicians occasionally work on when Shatner is hamming it up on the bridge.

The second number would be the volume if all the internal machinery were removed and it was a shell composed only of the hull and maybe whatever structure was necessary to keep it from crumbling under its own mass.

The length/width/height are well-known, but given its irregular shape I
m having difficulty deciding what the volume itself might be. Has this ever been discussed or written down, or is it calculable?

Comment: Trying to determine if it will float?

Comment: 211,248m³, apparently. http://www.st-v-sw.net/STSWvolumetrics.html

Comment: @Valorum This was much more specific than I hoped for. Feel free to leave it as a proper answer so I can upvote it. The math on that link looks plausible, and it includes many other starships besides, which will help with my project.

Comment: @JohnO - I lack the capacity (and will) to verify the figures on that site. By all means post it as a self-answer if you're happy with the numbers.

Comment: No bloody A, B, C, _or D_?!

Comment: I worked this out in the early 80s when trying to write up the Enterprise (as close as possible) in the _Traveller_ RPG's _High Guard_ rules.  I don't remember the result, though.

Comment: @LAK Reading the link more carefully, it seems their methodology is to find some high resolution 3d model and scale that up to reported length/width. Presumably there is some feature in Blender (or some macro they've written) that then allows it to calculate volume. It'd be difficult to argue that this is inadequate or excessively inaccurate.

Comment: @zabeus Those numbers are on the link too, and welcome. But I couldn't come here with a laundry list and not have the question closed, so I limited what was asked for. Now I just need the space shuttle, the Nimitz, a Whitestar, an SGC Daedalus-class, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd wager on it being around 2.8 million cubic metres. In S01E07 of the original series,'Mudd's Women' it is mentioned that the ship is almost 1 million gross tonnes. In modern nautical terms, gross tonnage is a measure of volume, not mass. And each gross tonne is equal to around 2.83 cubic metres of internal volume. Assuming they're working on the same system, you get around 2.8 million cubic metres for the whole ship.
Disclaimer, I've only seen episodes 1-7 of the original series.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any evidence the conversion factor applies to *Star Trek*, or a backup source for your estimate (at least to half an order of magnitude)?  At c.300m length, and approximately half that in height and width, the bounding box for the *Enterprise* would be less than 7 million cubic metres, so your estimate would require the *Enterprise* to fill nearly half of that volumetric space.

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth, youtuber ECHenry estimated 285,000 habitable cubic meters for a Constitution class and 340,000 for a Miranda class.  Which makes sense despite it being counterintuitive at first glance.  The secondary hull if the Constitution isn't as big as the rectangular expansion of the Miranda saucer.

Disclaimer: the is for the refit class so TOS Enterprise will be less based on the saucer radius.